# Is it possible to control how a function vectorize a np.array as parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, function, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to get advantage of the parallel processing of functions whit np.arrays as parameters, and this is just an simplified example of a recurrent issue that I get.

When I write a function which receives np.arrays as parameter to be vectorized, I can't control how it should vectorize the input. For example, in this case, I'm trying to make a tensordot multiplication of W and X arrays, but X aggregated with an "1" as its first coordenate. Of course, I will send an np.array with many Xs inside. Unfortunatly, the interpreter doesn't vectorize X trying to do the aggregating, and so it crushes.

The desired result is the commented line (where the interpreter vectorize the input correctly), but I would like to know if there is any way to control the vectorization of the function to make work something like the first line.

```
def h(X,W):
    return np.tensordot( np.r_[1,X],W, (0,0) )      # dimensions error!
    #return W[0] + np.tensordot( X, W[1:], (0,0) )  # desired result
    

W = np.array([0,1,2])   # plane coeffs

X0 = np.arange(4+1)
X1 = np.arange(5+1)
X0,X1 = np.meshgrid(X0,X1)
X = np.array([X0,X1])

fx = h(X,W)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe( X0, X1, fx,  linewidth=0.5,color='b')
plt.show()
```

PD: The example is complete, it will graph an 4 x 5 grid of the plane z = 0 + 1*x + 2*y

Comment: `tenordot` can be awkward to use.  Try use `dot`, `matmul` or `einsum`.  For a start loops are ok, we can fix that later.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, but I use `tensordot` because it lets me define over which dimension I make the product. Even in my toy example, to use the other options, I would need to "rotate" conveniently the X array to make it work properly; and remember that it's just a simplified example of my real cases.

Comment: The reason for the dimension error is because numpy does not expand the 1 into a vector of ones. You could simply do `np.r_[np.ones(X[0].shape)[None,:], X]` This will expand the one to match the dimension appropriately without the need of knowing what the dimensions are

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu! I was generating the dimension error. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables:

```
In [41]: W = np.array([0,1,2])   # plane coeffs
    ...: 
    ...: X0 = np.arange(4+1)
    ...: X1 = np.arange(5+1)
    ...: X0,X1 = np.meshgrid(X0,X1)
    ...: X = np.array([X0,X1])
In [42]: W.shape
Out[42]: (3,)
In [43]: X.shape
Out[43]: (2, 6, 5)
```

With `meshgrid` you might want to use `index='ij'`.  But that doesn't matter with the following calculations

```
In [44]: temp=W[0]+np.tensordot(X, W[1:], (0,0))
In [45]: temp.shape
Out[45]: (6, 5)
```

A way to do the same without separating out `W[0]`, is to expand `X` to (3,6,5)

```
In [46]: Xnew = np.concatenate((np.ones((1,6,5),X.dtype),X), axis=0)
In [47]: Xnew.shape
Out[47]: (3, 6, 5)
In [48]: temp2 = np.tensordot(Xnew,W, (0,0))
In [49]: temp2.shape
Out[49]: (6, 5)
In [50]: np.allclose(temp,temp2)
Out[50]: True
```

Usually when we talk about `numpy` vectorizing we mean replacing python level iteration with compiled iteration in numpy methods.  Here I don't think the second helps.  It's only replacing one separate addition, while increasing the size of the `dot` product - so there's the added time of `concatenate` plus more time in the `dot`.  "vectorization" is not worth it if we are replacing a few iterations on a complex task with a more complex task.

This is actually faster:

```
temp3 = W[0]+W[1]*X0+W[2]*X1
```

`tensordot` applies `reshape` and `transpose` to the arguments to reduce the problem to single call to `np.dot`.  It may then reshape results.

`einsum` is better than `tensordot` (at least in speed):

```
temp=W[0]+np.einsum('ijk,i->jk',X,W[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @hpaulj! While I'm learning more about numpy and vectorization, I think that I should measure times to see the efficiency of my programs, could you recomend me any library or fuction to do it properly in Python?

Comment: `timeit` is widely used on SO.  I do most of my answers in `ipython`, and `timeit` is particularly easy to use there.